# How to create a Vue.js sign up flow with multiple Views

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am new to web development and am working on a project with Vue.js and Firebase. I currently have an application that allows a user to log in or sign up and is then routed to the default HelloWorld page once authenticated. However, I am trying to add an extra step to my sign up flow.

How it works currently:

1. The user goes to sign up view (`SignUp.vue`)
2. The user enters information into a form. This information is used to create the user in Firebase.
3. The User is then routed to `Home.vue`

What I would like to do:

1. The user goes to sign up view (`SignUp.vue`)
2. The user enters information into a form. This information is used to create the user in Firebase.
3. **The user is presented with another form where they enter their phone number (or any other data). This data is stored in Firestore.**
4. The user is then routed to `Home.vue`

In `SignUp.vue`, once the user is authenticated with Firebase, I change views with: `this.$router.replace('/home')`

However, replacing this with: `this.$router.replace('/phone')` to route to my phone collection view does not work.

I am simply trying to add an additional page to the sign-up flow, but am not sure how to configure my Vue router to do so. The way it is currently configured, as soon as the user is authenticated in Firebase, they are automatically taken to the home page.

Here is my router configuration:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

import Home from '@/views/Home';
import Login from '@/views/Login';
import SignUp from '@/views/SignUp';
import Phone from '@/views/Phone';

Vue.use(Router);

const router = new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '*',
            redirect: '/login'
        },
        {
            path: '/',
            redirect: '/login'
        },
        {
            path: '/login',
            name: 'Login',
            component: Login
        },
        {
            path: '/sign-up',
            name: 'SignUp',
            component: SignUp
        },
        {
            path: '/phone',
            name: 'Phone',
            component: Phone
        },
        {
            path: '/home',
            name: 'Home',
            component: Home,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

And here is where I check for an authenticated user and load the view accordingly in `router.js`:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);

    if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
        next('login');
    } else if (!requiresAuth && currentUser) {
        next('home');
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

How do I configure my router so that when a user logs in to an existing account they go directly to `home`, while a new user must visit an additional page (`phone`), before being taken to `home`?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: well youve kinda given a solution yourself in the question. Rewrite the `beforeEach` function to take into account the different auth statuses. Im assuming the `/phone`  page is phone verification. Check if the current user has a phone verified, if not send it to the /phone page.

Comment: I added requiresPhone: true to the meta for the Home component, and I also changed my else if to: else if (!requiresAuth && !requiresPhone && currentUser), but vue is still routing me to the home page...any ideas? @Flame